# NestJS, Typeorm, SQL Server - failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect to a locally running a SQL Server database using Typeorm and nestJS.

I have created a new database in SSMS Express, and created a new login, giving the user `db_owner` permissions for the given database.

I have installed the following packages:

```
@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.0",
"mssql": "^8.1.2",
```

This is the error that I receive:

> [Nest] 25180  - 07/29/2022, 10:50:42 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> at connectListener (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17)
> at Connection.onConnect (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1763:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1906:18)
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2221:12)
> at callback (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2006:21)
> at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connector.ts:118:14)
> at Socket.onError (C:\Projects\lucas\node_modules\tedious\src\connector.ts:144:12)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)

This is my configuration for the connection to the database:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mssql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 1433,
      username: 'timetracker_user',
      password: 'ihaveagun',
      database: 'timetracker',
      // entities: [User], // define entities manually
      autoLoadEntities: true, // auto loads all entities registered through the forFeature() method
      synchronize: true, // should be set to false in production.
    }),
```

The largest issue that I am having is that I cannot find the resources to help me. When googling, I found articles on enabling TCP/IP for SQL Server, however when researching on how to do this, all resources point to MS Server tools. I am doing this on Windows 10 machine and I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18.

At this stage, I simply want to connect to my db locally, this is for learning purposes.

Could I please get some help on how to debug and fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: When you installed SQL Server Express it should also have installed SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager. Have you tried opening it, going to Server Protocols (for your Express instance) and enabling the TCP/IP protocol there?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection problem seems to be related with SQL Configuration. Please try the following:

1. Be sure server authentication is set to 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'. Open SSMS, right click server, select properties and under security option change the default selection.
2. As AlwaysLearning mentioned open SQL Server Configuration Manager and go to 'SQL Server Network Configuration'. Then under 'Protocols for MSSQLSERVER' enable both 'Named Pipes' and 'TCP/IP'.
3. Finally, restart is required for changes to take effect. Open Windows Services and restart MSSQL Server.